# Passing parameter from Drupal Panel page into View

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-panels

I am having issues using View display in a Panel, on Drupal 7 (using Panopoly), from one of the Pages in our Drupal site. We are having problems passing parameters from Panels into Views.

I would like to allow passing the Taxonomy Name (in lowercase), from a Page (using Panels), to one of the Views on that page.
At the same time, I would like to pass the Taxonomy ID (tid) in the same manner.
Then, with Contextual Filters (which are used in the View), I would like to filter those news articles.

For example, it should allow both:
**news/3** and **news/latest**, showing same results.

Could someone help me or point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, that I am understood you correctly, but if you want to pass the different values for the few views, you may use the "Contextual filters" for each of them. In View "Pane settings" set "Argument input" parameter to "From context" point, and then choose a value, that you need.
This video can explain, how to do it.
http://nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager-part-5-views-content-panes-basics

Or you can add the exposed filters to your View, and enable "Use exposed widgets form as pane configuration" option in "Allow settings" menu. Then you will be able to configure filter values in your panel pane settings form.

Comment: Thanks!

Actually, I am already using Contextual Filters in the View. I am filtering by **either** TID or Tax Name. But, I would like to allow filtering by any of them.

In the Panel, I am passing the params as /news/%taxonomy_name (as string), then assigning the Context (taxonomy term). 
I am able to use /news/latest .
But then, I am not able to have /news/3 working :(

Thanks in advance!